# Trying get var object from facebook graph but can seem to echo the variable I need

Tags: php

I am getting facebook graph information for a URL. So I can echo how many shares this URL has had on facebook.

This is how I am getting the graph object...

```
$facebook = json_decode(file_get_contents( "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=".get_permalink()), TRUE);
```

and if I print this...

```
print_r( $facebook );
```

it outputs this array...

```
Array
(
    [http://mysite.co.uk/wp/2013/08/hello-world/] => Array
        (
            [id] => http://mysite.co.uk/wp/2013/08/hello-world/
            [shares] => 3
        )

)
```

OK so technically if I am successfully getting this array then I can output my share count like so...

```
echo $facebook['shares'];
```

But it is not working! Nothing is being echo'ed.

Can any please enlighten me to where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
echo $facebook['http://mysite.co.uk/wp/2013/08/hello-world/']['shares'];
```

Your reply is an array in another array, the first key is `'http://mysite.co.uk/wp/2013/08/hello-world/'`.

You could also do

```
$a=array_values($facebook);
echo $a[0]['shares'];
```

or

```
list($a)=array_values($facebook);
echo $a['shares'];
```

Comment: Is no shorter way to do this? Or is this the only way?